# Since HTTP 2.0 is rolling out, are tricks like asset bundle still necessary?

Tags: http, optimization

How can we know how many browsers support HTTP 2.0?

Comment: That's three questions.  The last one is subjective and not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @Schwern, I removed the last one, All I want to know is how could be know how many old browsers which do not support http 2.0 or SPDY are out there, so that we can get the idea of when all of tricks like sprite graphic, putting encoded images in CSS, bundling all js in one files, etc will be totally pointless. Would you please kindly help me rephrase that? My English is not very good..Sorry about that.

Comment: That third question turned out to be the most interesting part for me to answer. :)

Comment: See, It may be slightly objective, but it is not irrelevant. Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it should benefit many web developers and webmasters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can we know how many browsers support HTTP 2.0?

[A simple Wikipedia search will tell you.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2#Browser_support)  They cover [at least 60% of the market](http://gs.statcounter.com/#all-browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201402-201502) and probably more once you pick apart the less than 10% browsers.  That's pretty good for something that's only been a standard for a month.

This is a standard people have been waiting for for a *long* time.  It's based on an existing protocol, [SPDY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY), that's had some real world vetting.  It gives some immediate performance boosts, and performance in browsers is king.  Rapid adoption by browsers and servers is likely.  Everyone wants this.  Nobody wants to allow their competitors such a significant performance edge.

> Since http 2.0 is rolling out, does tricks like asset bundle still be necessary?

HTTP/2 is designed to solve many of the existing performance problems of HTTP/1.1.  There should be less need for tricks to bundle multiple assets together into one HTTP request.

With HTTP/2 multiple requests can be performed in a single connection.  An HTTP/2 server can also push extra content to the client before the client requests, allowing it to pre-load page assets in a single request and even before the HTML is downloaded and parsed.

[This article has more details.](http://www.engadget.com/2015/02/24/what-you-need-to-know-about-http-2/)

> When can we move on to the future of technologies and stop those dirty optimizations designed mainly for HTTP 1?

Three things have to happen.

- Chrome has to turn on their support by default.

[This will happen quickly](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2882018/google-chrome-embraces-the-faster-more-secure-next-gen-http-20-standard.html).  Then give a little time for the upgrade to trickle out to your users.

- You have to use HTTPS everywhere.

Most browsers right now only support HTTP/2 over TLS.  I think everyone was expecting HTTP/2 to only work encrypted to force everyone to secure their web sites.  Sort of a carrot/stick, "you want better performance?  Turn on basic security."  I think the browser makers are going to stick with the "encrypted only" plan anyway.  It's in their best interest to promote a secure web.

- You have to decide what percentage of your users get degraded performance.

Unlike something like CSS support, HTTP/2 support does not affect your content.  Its benefits are mostly performance.  You don't *need* HTTP/1.1 hacks.  Your site will still look and act the same for HTTP/1.1 if you get rid of them.  It's up to you when you want to stop putting in the extra work to maintain.

Like any other hack, hopefully your web framework is doing it for you.  If you're manually stitching together icons into a single image, you're doing it wrong.  There are all sorts of frameworks which should make this all transparent to you.

It doesn't have to be an all-or-nothing thing either.  As the percentage of HTTP/1.1 connections to your site drops, you can do a cost/benefit analysis and start removing the HTTP/1.1 optimizations which are the most hassle and the least benefit.  The ones that are basically free, leave them in.

Like any other web protocol, the question is how fast will people upgrade?  These days, most browsers update automatically.  Mobile users, and desktop Firefox and Chrome users, will upgrade quickly.  That's 60-80% of the market.

As always, IE is the problem.  While the newest version of IE already supports HTTP/2, it's only available in Windows 10 which isn't even out yet.  All those existing Windows users will likely never upgrade.  It's not in Microsoft's best interest to backport support into old versions of Windows or IE.  In fact, they just announced they're [replacing IE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartan_%28browser%29).  So that's probably 20% of the web population permanently left behind.  The statistics for your site will vary.

Large institutional installations like governments, universities and corporations will also be slow to upgrade.  Regardless of what browser they have standardized on, they often disable automatic updates in order to more tightly control their environment.  If this is a large chunk of your users, you may not be willing to drop the HTTP/1.1 hacks for years.

It will be up to you to monitor how people are connecting to your web site, and how much effort you want to put into optimizing it for an increasingly shrinking portion of your users.  The answer is "it depends on who your users are" and "whenever you decide you're ready".

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I think currently only a few browsers support HTTP 2.0, a slightly larger amount support SPDY, and thanks to IE, we probably won't be able to see the day come any soon. So most of old optimization methods are still critical. Can I interpret it this way?

Comment: @ParisQian No, that's not my interpretation of the situation.  I've extensively updated the answer to explain.